# Getting field name and field value with parameter expansion

Tags: bash

I have a bash variable named `flentry` that consists of

```
File: Value
```

or

```
+ Value
```

Have used

```
fld="${flentry%[[:blank:]]*}"
```

and

```
fl="${flentry#*[[:blank:]]}"
```

to get the field name `File:` and `+`, whereas `fl` gets the value.

Looks as if bash parameter expansion uses regex patterns, or am I wrong?

I understand that `%` remove shortest trailing match, whilst `#` removes smallest trailing match.  But I am having difficulty seeing how `fld` and `fl` get the field name and field value respectively.

Comment: Parameter expansion uses the rules described in the bash manual page under *Pattern Matching*. **They are different from regular expression patterns**. See for example [How do regular expressions differ from wildcards used to filter files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57957/how-do-regular-expressions-differ-from-wildcards-used-to-filter-files)

Comment: How exactly are `fld` and `fl` being made? Whilst `*` means zero or more matches, I fail to see what `"${flentry#*[[:blank:]]}"` tries to match because the `*` immediately follows `#`.

Comment: @steeldriver Rules are surely different from regular expression patterns.  Does your comment mean that `*[[:blank:]]` uses a * as wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

The forms `${parameter#word}`, `${parameter%word}`, `${parameter##word}` and `${parameter%%word}` are part of the POSIX specification for [Parameter Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02). In all cases, `word` is treated the same as a filename generation ("glob") expression as described in [Pattern Matching Notation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13). Although these patterns display some superficial similarities with regular expressions, they are **not** regular expressions - see for example [How do regular expressions differ from wildcards used to filter files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57957/how-do-regular-expressions-differ-from-wildcards-used-to-filter-files).

The bash shell extends that specification in a number of ways; for example

- bash permits regex-style `[^...]` as an alternative to POSIX `[!...]` for inverting a character set
- (when the `extglob` shell option is enabled) bash supports ksh-style extended globs like `+(foo|bar)` that provide regex-like alternation and quantifier capabilities.

For full details refer to the bash manual's own section on [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching).

So `fld="${flentry%[[:blank:]]*}"` expands the variable `flentry`, removing from its end the shortest substring matching a blank (space or tab) character followed by zero or more other characters (i.e. everything from the *last* space or tab to the end of the string). If `flentry` contains the string `File: Value`, the result is therefore `File:`.

Similarly, `fl="${flentry#*[[:blank:]]}"` expands `flentry`, removing from its start the shortest substring matching zero or more characters followed by a space or tab (i.e. everything from the start of the string up to and including the *first* space or tab), resulting in `Value`.

Note that this way of separating field name and value will fail if either or both contain whitespace. It looks like you should really be using `:[[:blank:]]` as the delimiter.

Comment: I have figured out my confusion.  Had been confusing a single `*` with `*(pattern-list)`.  As I assumed that `"${flentry#*[[:blank:]]}"` uses `*(pattern-list)` with `pattern-list` being `[[:blank:]]`.

Comment: The glob pattern `*` does not match a space, right?

Comment: @Nameh `*` *does* match space; hence if `var='foo bar baz'` for example, `echo "${var##* }"` results in just `baz` (i.e. `*` consumes everything up to the last space)